# jquery.post is not working in codeinniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2, .post

view file code :

```
<div id="fb" align="center">
<?php 
echo form_open('contact/submit');
echo form_input('name', 'Name', 'id="name"').'<br>';
echo form_input('email', 'Email', 'id="email"').'<br>';
$data = array('name' => 'message', 'cols' => 35, 'rows' => 12);
echo form_textarea($data, 'Message', 'id="mesage"').'<br>';
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'id="submit"').'<br>';
echo form_close();  
?>
```

script jquery post is not working.

```
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.post("http://localhost/forhad/index.php/contact/submit", {'bar':'foo'}, function(data) {
             alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

controller:

```
function submit()
    {
        echo 'Thanks!';
    }
```

i tried a lot in various way bt i failed, jquery get,load method works fine, but when i try to use jquery post nothing happens.
 please help me.thnx

Answer (score 0):

The are numerous exmaples on the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) under jquery post. You say you have tried various ways - Which ones of these have you tried?

What happens when you click the submit button? If you are using chrome you could check the inspector and see what fires - if any post request is fired.

try this inside your click event:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html',{'bar':'foo'}, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: nothing happens,
remain same as before submitting the form.

i read jquery docs and google search about CI jquery, i tried many example code from docs bt but i fails. jquery post is not working, even ajax alos not working.  

thnx for replay...

Comment: stick in some `console.log`'ing and see if you can pinpoint where abouts it is failing

Comment: Do you have CSRF enabled within the config? When this is enabled, you will have to insert the CSRF Token hidden input field as one of the form variables you send, assuming it's on the same site?